# getElementsByTagName stopping at triangle bracket

Tags: javascript, xml, getelementsbytagname

I am using `getElementsByTagName` in this context

```
 TheTitle = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ArticleTitle")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

to obtain the node value but when the text includes triangle brackets such as:

```
<ArticleTitle>"The Cat Sat on The <i>Mat</i>"</ArticleTitle>
```

I am only able to retrieve

```
The Cat Sat on The
```

How can I prevent triangle brackets in the node text from prematurely ending text capture?

Comment: can you show code that demonstrates what you're doing

Comment: Is this a part of an html page (is it on the DOM)? Is it xml or are you using JavaScript?

Comment: @AaronJ accessing xml file stored in a js variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ArticleTitle>"The Cat Sat on The <i>Mat</i>"</ArticleTitle>` has three child nodes

1. text node: `The Cat Sat on The`
2. `<i>` node with `<i>Mat</i>`
3. text node `"`

So, `.childNodes[0].nodeValue;` will, of course, be just `The Cat Sat on The`

To fix, use:

```
TheTitle = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ArticleTitle")[i].textContent;
```

instead

```js
let doc = `<xml><ArticleTitle>"The Cat Sat on The <i>Mat</i>"</ArticleTitle></xml>`;
let xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(doc, 'text/xml');
let TheTitle = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ArticleTitle")[0].textContent;
console.log(TheTitle);
```

Comment: does not change result

Comment: yes i can see it works on the example but not in my code

Comment: So ... I don't know what `i` is .. perhaps you're doing something completely different in your *real code* @haz